# move g.drawstring 'x' that had been created on picturebox

Tags: c#

I am trying to move the 'x' that has been created by these codes. What do I have to add in so that the 'x' would be able to MOVE AGAIN? In the case it is placed not in the position I would want it to be in.

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.Handle))
{
    using (Font myFont = new Font("Calibri", 8))
    {
        g.DrawString("X", myFont, Brushes.Red, new PointF(e.X, e.Y));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are splattering pixels directly onto the window, very rarely the correct thing to do.  "Moving" it requires cleaning up the splatter first, call pictureBox1.Refresh().  Always favor using the Paint event instead.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Is it possible if you could give me an example? I have been stuck at this for quite some time. I desperately need help :(

Comment: Please explain what you meant by move?  Is that mouse move?

Comment: what i would like is the drawstring will place the 'x' on my picturebox i require the 'x' to be able to be moved once again as there might be times where you have placed it not at the correct position and you want to change the position. Do you know of any codes that call allow the calling of g.drawstring to be moved?

Comment: Do not create a Graphics object with FromHwnd. Handle the picturebox's Paint event. Do all your painting in there (with `e.Graphics`). When you want to "move" the X, change some variables that the paint method looks at, and call Refresh on the picturebox.

Comment: do i use OnPaint to produce the 'x'? what do you mean by change the variables? Sorry a beginner here..

Comment: I added an answer with a simple example.

Comment: what I mean is if I would like to place the X at the cursor position instead of a fixed number do i use cursor.position.x for the posX?

Answer (score 0):

Do not create a Graphics object with `FromHwnd`. Handle the picturebox's Paint event. Do all your painting in there (with e.Graphics).

When you want to "move" the X, change some variables that the paint method looks at, and call Refresh on the picturebox.

Here's a simple example:

```
private int posX = 10;
private int posY = 10;
private Font font = new Font("Calibri", 8);

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString("x", font, Brushes.Black, posX, posY);
}

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    posX += 10;
    posY += 10;
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}
```